# Can a set of random numbers contain floating point numbers?

Tags: random-variables, random

When we are considering a set of random numbers between 1 and 100 or any other number(s) then is it necessary that the numbers should always be an Integer. Can the number be a floating point number like 4.35678 ?

Comment: If you want it to be so, then yes of course. Just ensure that your probabilities add up to 100%.

Comment: In general, given a collection of objects, we can assign probabilities to suitable subsets of the collection. The suitable subsets are called measurable sets and the probabilities are only defined on these subsets. For finite collections of objects, the measurable sets are all possible subsets so these things do not get discussed in this context.

Comment: If there is an uncountable number of objects, then at most a countable number can have a non zero probability.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are asked, you are free to build any distribution in any set you want. You can have $x\sim[1,100]\cap\mathbb{N}$ or $x\sim[1,100]\cap\mathbb{Q}$. The last case can include any rational (floating point) numbers you want.

Comment: Can we consider R rather than Q or N.

Comment: Remember probabilities are always defined over sets, so, you can use any set you want, as pointed out, provided that all your probabilites add up to 100%. Can it be finite | countable infinite | uncountable infinite? Yes to all of these

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the distribution. As long as it is a probability space (which is a set where each subset has been assigned a probability along with certain axioms which assert that this behaves like how you would expect probability to behave), it is a valid random distribution. You can even restrict your set to only return numbers of a certain type, like ones which only have certain digits.